# Inherit other file.py globals

Tags: python, inheritance, global

how do you inherit globals from other .py file?

Example:
globals.py

```
test = 'testValue'
```

index.py

```
from globals import *

def setGlobals():
    global test
    test = 'new Value' # Setting new value to project global  

setGlobals()
```

help.py

```
from globals import *
print test # Should print out 'new Value', but it prints 'testValue'
```

I wish to have one file full of constants and global variables that is set by another file and also used by other files. In this example I set new value to global variable `test` in `index.py` and wish to use new value in `help.py`. Am I using the wrong approach for python? Thank you.

EDIT:
Sequence of events is same as exampled, e.g. first I import, set new value and then try printing out newly set value from another file.

Comment: You're not calling `setGlobals` in the example program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python modules are objects. When you do an import, you are copying and possibly renaming the attributes of one module into the current module. However, this only copies the value (or more specifically copies the reference by value). If the imported module is later changed, your copy won't be. One possible approach is to try defining your globals in the second module as properties, but I'm not sure if that even works.

However, what you are trying to do is terrible design anyway. You need to rethink why you want to have global values being accessed and modified everywhere. Try refactoring your code and replacing anything left with dependency injection. For example, replace your globals module with a configuration object that you can pass around to whoever needs it.

Comment: Dependency injection isn't an option, I wish to have one setter function for globals that is only called startup or how to say .. constructor? So if i would have class full of globals design would be better?

Comment: Yes. Then you just need to create the globals object at startup and pass it around. If you won't be modifying it after creation, you can even make it a namedtuple.

Comment: That works, but design wise, is it horribly wrong? I grew up with c++ and this kind of things are OK.

Comment: @krizajB: whoever told you globals are ok in C++ was misled.

Comment: @krizajB: I never use global variables in my own code, except in one-off scripts. When I use them, it's because I'm forced by a library, and I try to avoid such libraries. I agree with Antimony that you might want to rethink your design.

Comment: I understand, and I am agree with you. I am checking what namedtuple does, would you accept such a work around i.e. creating class, set class variables only once and reuse them (only getters)?

Comment: In Python you don't even need getters.

Comment: Ye, only said it to explicitly announce I will only use them, not set them. Anyway, works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to:

- [How do I share global variables across modules? - python](https://www.edureka.co/community/52900/how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules-python)

Inside `index.py` you would remove:

```
global test
```

Then you would change:

```
test = 'new Value' # Setting new value to project global
```

To:

```
globals.test = 'new Value' # Setting new value to project global
```

In `help.py` you would change:

```
print test # Should print out 'new Value', but it prints 'testValue'
```

To:

```
print globals.test # Should print out 'new Value', but it prints 'testValue'
```

I'm actually working on a similar project tonight so will comeback and confirm website's correctness later (although it makes sense it is correct).

It seems confirmed by this link:

- http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules.htm

As an aside I'm somewhat surprised stack overflow doesn't have an answer on this yet other than the too often occurring accepted answer of "You can't do that". I don't have `c++` experience like you do in comments. But I have used `c` and psuedo `c#` and having header files you include for global variables seems like a no-brainer and not something to be shunned. I do it in Linux `bash` all the time with `source config.sh`, etc.